# How to convert all email addresses to links and put them into a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following code in one my components:

```
return <Box>{props.children}</Box>
```

All this does is return the contents in a nicely formatted `<div>` box. Now what I want to do is if there are any email addresses in `props.children`, I want to render those as links. So for example, if the content was as follows:

```
Hi my name is Foo, you can contact me at foo@bar.com.
```

Then I would like the component to return this:

```
<div class="box">
  Hi my name is Foo, you can contact me at <a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">foo@bar.com</a>.
<div>
```

How do I do this? I was thinking of using regex to find all email addresses and add the `<a>` tags to them, but that didn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated here!

Comment: Just a clarification. The content is dynamic right?

Comment: If your problem is that the `regex` doesn't work, it may help to post the regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
const str = `Hi my name is Foo, you can contact me at foo@bar.com, foo@yan.net`;


console.log(str.replace(/(\w+@\w+.\w+)+/g, "<a href='mailto:$1'>$1</a>"));
```

Output:

```
"Hi my name is Foo, you can contact me at <a href='mailto:foo@bar.com'>foo@bar.com</a>, <a href='mailto:foo@yan.net'>foo@yan.net</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that "***props.chaildren***" text has only one email.

```
import React from 'react';

function isContainEmail() {
    //Write your logic to find this and I am assuming this function will return email address otherwise null
    return 'foo@bar.com';
}
function splitByEmail() {
    //  Do your logic to split the email from text and send both part in a array
    return [
        'Hi my name is Foo, you can contact me at',
        '. Some others line go here',
    ];
}
function generateTemplateForUser(text) {
    const email = isContainEmail(text);
    if (!email) return <div className='box'>{text}</div>;
    const linkProps = {
        href: `mailto:${email}`,
    };
    const textSplittedByEmail = splitByEmail(text);
    return (
        <div className='box'>
            {textSplittedByEmail[0]} <a {...linkProps}> {email}</a>
            {textSplittedByEmail[1]}
        </div>
    );
}
function App(props) {
    return (
        <>
            {/* Please pass your props.children value in place of hardcoded value */}
            {generateTemplateForUser(
                'Hi my name is Foo, you can contact me at foo@bar.com. Some others line go here....',
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This solution will not work if you can have multiple emails in your text. Feel free to comment if you have any doubts.

**Update**

If you have multiple emails in text, then please use [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser).

```
import React from 'react';
import parser from 'html-react-parser';
// Copy from @denelvis's answer
const formatText = (text) => {
  return text.replace(/(\w+@\w+.\w+)+/g, "<a href='mailto:$1'>$1</a>");
};
function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Please pass your props.children value in place of hardcoded value */}
      {parser(
        formatText(
          'Hi my name is Foo, you can contact me at foo@bar.com. Some others line go here.Hi my name is Dummy, you can contact me at foo@bar.com'
        )
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8tje2o?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Unfortunately, the `props.children` can have multiple emails.

Comment: Then you should use "html-react-parser". I have updated the code on Stackblitz. Please check it out and feel free to comment if you have any doubts. I have used the @denelvis logic to replace emails text iwith its  anchor tag.